# JavaScript module pattern / organization / sub-modules

Tags: javascript, namespaces, module-pattern

1. I would like to know what's the
   difference
   (advantages/disadvantages) between
   the following patterns.
2. How can I create sub modules based
       on the module pattern?

My goal is to have my **js** organized into **multiple files** that are **lazy loaded** but have one namespace.

For example:

SO.global (global.js)
SO.global.registration (registration.js) <- load

```
var SO = function(){

    var CONSTANT = 'Z';

    function createX(){
      alert("create X");
    }

    function getY(){
       alert("get Y");
    }
    return{
      create:createX,
      get:getY
    }
}();

//SO.createX(); 
//SO.getY();
```

VS.

```
var SO = (function() {

    var CONSTANT = 'Z';

    function createX(){
      alert("create X");
    }

    function getY(){
       alert("get Y");
    }

    return {
      create:createX,
      get:getY
    }

} ());
```

Comment: There is no difference between the two examples....one has parens around it but they should do the same thing.

Comment: The additional parens in the second example are being used by some folks to indicate that the function expression is called immediately.

Comment: I think the parens are in the wrong place for that convention though. I believe it's usually written as (function(){...})()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered [Require.JS](http://requirejs.org/)?  It attempts to provide the following solution:

- Some sort of #include/import/require
- ability to load nested dependencies
- ease of use for developer but then backed by an optimization tool that helps deployment

Require.JS implements the [Module/Asynchronous Definition](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/AsynchronousDefinition) spec defined by Common.JS

Answer (score 3):

Here's a good read: http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/no-love-for-module-pattern, and another: http://lamb.cc/blog/category/javascript/

YUI uses it avidly, as do I, I haven't found any situations where I was restricted by it, and it nicely integrates with the YUI dependency loader for custom Modules.

(Sorry, I realise this isn't a complete answer, but there's some untampered info for you)

Comment: These links have just added a couple of months on my "skills-todo" pipeline.

Comment: The first link is weird. It's like he is arguing against the use of private variables.

Comment: @cherouvim, agreed, i'm about... 70% of the way through the brain freak involved (for me anyway)

Comment: @david, I gleaned the same feeling, which added another 25% of investigative work, including the comments on his article which are interesting also

Comment: One thing I will say about the Snook article, the objection to the module-pattern--the objection which says that it requires you to edit code to fish out hidden data--is not quite right. There's a surprisingly easy workaround that I use with Firebug. We need only set a conditional breakpoint inside a function with access to the private data, then set the condition on the breakpoint to `!console.log(hiddenVar)`. The breakpoint won't ever break (unless you want it to, in which case, you can remove the `!`), but causing the function to execute will now log my private data for easy inspection.

Comment: I could alternatively set the breakpoint condition to `(window._hidden = hiddenVar, 0)` so I can manipulate or more carefully inspect the formerly hidden data.